# How to learn password reset oob code in Firebase Auth REST API?

Tags: firebase, rest, curl, firebase-authentication

I am sending a password reset request using Firebase Auth REST API [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D). The link is sent via e-mail.

It asks for oobCode in the verify password reset code service.
[https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:resetPassword?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:resetPassword?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

In the Firebase documentation, for oobCode it says "The email action code sent to the user's email for resetting the password." It says, but the link is sent via e-mail, but the oobCode is not. oobCode is not set in the Firebase console Authentication e-mail template section.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth?hl=tr#section-verify-password-reset-code

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:resetPassword?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"oobCode":"[PASSWORD_RESET_CODE]"}'
```

Where to learn oobCode? Is it possible to get oobCode by breaking %LINK% in email theme?

Comment: Please edit the following information into your question: What data did you provide to `accounts:sendOobCode`? What response did you get when you made the request? Did the user receive an email? Did that email contain a reset password link? What data is contained in that link (domain, path, GET parameters)? What does that link point to (your server, Firebase Hosting, etc.)?

Comment: You may also find the [Custom Email Action Link Handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) documentation of use. It describes how to create a webpage that you host to handle the links sent via email. To use them, you'll need to pass certain parameters to `accounts:sendOobCode`.

Comment: In the document "The email action code sent to the user's email for resetting the password." has knowledge. But only the link is returned to the user. @samthecodingman

Comment: Is that because you are sending `returnOobLink=true` with the request to `accounts:sendOobCode`? If that's the case, an email is not sent and you are expected to send that link in your own email template to the user as mentioned in [the response documentation for `accounts:sendOobCode`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/GetOobCodeResponse). Please answer the above questions to prevent the need for back-and-forth messages.

Comment: As a result, the kind and email fields are returned. The mail is going. The e-mail content includes the project name, e-mail address and reset link.

When I add "returnOobLink": true to the query body, an "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION" error is returned. @samthecodingman